# label in eqnarray after brackets

Tags: labels, eqnarray

[image]

May I know how to add labels for the constraints in the LP set such as (3b), (3c), etc.? It seems like once I added `\right}`, the label function does not work anymore.

And this is what I have now:

```
\begin{subequations} \label{}
    \begin{eqnarray}
    && \zeta_{ij} = f_{ij}(x) \ ,\ i\in I, j \in J       \\
    &{\mathcal{LP}}:=&\left\{ %(x,y): \quad 
    \begin{array}{ll}
    h_i(x) \leq 0 \ ,\ i\in I        \\
    l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i \\ 
    y \in \mathbb R_+  \\ 
    x \in \mathbb R_+^2  \times \mathbb Z_+^3 \times \mathbb B^1   \;     
    \end{array}
    \right\} \notag 
    \end{eqnarray} 
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I suspect that `subequations` is not set up to work with `eqnarray`.  It's really designed to work with `align` and other display environments from `amsmath`,

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

With combination of `equation` and `empheq` math environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:1}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:a}
\zeta_{ij} = f_{ij}(x) \ ,\ i\in I, j \in J       
    \end{equation}
\begin{empheq}[left=L\mathcal{LP}{\colon=}\empheqlbrace,right=\empheqrbrace]{align}
    &   h_i(x) \leq 0 \ ,\ i\in I   \label{eq:b} \\
    &   l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i       \label{eq:c}\\
    &   y \in \mathbb R_+           \label{eq:d}\\
    &   x \in \mathbb R_+^2  \times \mathbb Z_+^3 \times \mathbb B^1
                                    \label{eq:e}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```